# Hide complete table before a PHP search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP search form for searching in a SQL table.
All together it works great, but there is one thing I like to change.

The whole table is visible on the screen BEFORE the search.
I would like to mention only the records after a search.

Does anybody know to hide the table in PHP?
Many thanks in advance!

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$host = "******";
$user = "******";
$password = "******";
$database_name = "vangsten";
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user, $password, array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
$search=$_POST['search'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * FROM meldingen WHERE soort LIKE '%$search%' OR zone LIKE '%$search%'  LIMIT 0 , 10");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
         if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {

                echo "<table style=\"margin:50px auto;\">"; 
                echo "<tr><td>VISSOORT</td><td>LENGTE</td><td>AANTAL</td><td>ZONE</td></tr>";
            while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
                echo "<tr><td>";            
                echo $results['soort'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['lengte'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['aantal'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $results['zone'];
                echo "</td></tr>";              
            }
                echo "</table>";        
        } else {
            echo 'Nothing found';
        }
?>
```

Comment: Does the table show while searching or even if not searching at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because even when there is no search passed you will end up running the query: with `WHERE sort LIKE '%%'`

You should check if a search has been passed first

```
if(array_key_exists('search',$_POST) && !empty($_POST['search'])){
    $search=$_POST['search'];
    $query = $pdo->prepare("select * FROM meldingen WHERE soort LIKE '%$search%' OR zone LIKE '%$search%'  LIMIT 0 , 10");
    $query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
        echo "<table style=\"margin:50px auto;\">"; 
        echo "<tr><td>VISSOORT</td><td>LENGTE</td><td>AANTAL</td><td>ZONE</td></tr>";
        while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr><td>";            
            echo $results['soort'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $results['lengte'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $results['aantal'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $results['zone'];
            echo "</td></tr>";              
        }
        echo "</table>";        
    } else {
        echo 'Nothing found';
    }
}
```

- `array_key_exists('search',$_POST)` checks that there is a value with
  the key 'search;'
- `!empty($_POST['search'])` checks it is not just
  an empty string. (You may want to allow this)

You could use `isset($_POST['search'])` instead of `array_key_exists('search',$_POST)` but `array_key_exists` is better practice as `isset` still returns false if the value is `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user has clicked on the search button:

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    // do your table generation here
}
```